# Android Cursor starts at row 0

Tags: java, android, cursor

I have a programm where I create a Table:

```
 //CAR_TABLE COLUMNS
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_ID_BARCODE = "ID_BARCODE";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_Hersteller ="Hersteller";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_KFZTyp = "KFZTyp";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_Farbe = "Farbe";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_AbteilungID = "AbteilungID";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_SONDERAUSSTATTUNG ="Sonderausstattung";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_Ausgeliefert = "Ausgeliefert";
    public static final String CAR_COLUMN_ProgrammID ="ProgrammID";
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                String CREATE_CAR_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CARS + "(\n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_ID_BARCODE + " TEXT, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_Hersteller + " TEXT, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_KFZTyp + " TEXT, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_Farbe + " TEXT, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_AbteilungID + " INTEGER, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_Ausgeliefert + " TEXT, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_SONDERAUSSTATTUNG + " TEXT, \n" +
                        CAR_COLUMN_ProgrammID + " INTEGER \n" +
                        ");";
```

The database is created fine and I am able to add entries normally.

The problem is that, when I want to retrieve a row from the database, it tells me the following

```
03-11 16:00:00.470: E/CursorWindow(7465): Failed to read row 0, column 8 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 8 columns.
03-11 16:00:00.470: D/AndroidRuntime(7465): Shutting down VM
03-11 16:00:00.470: E/AndroidRuntime(7465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 16:00:00.470: E/AndroidRuntime(7465): Process: com.example.prog3, PID: 7465
03-11 16:00:00.470: E/AndroidRuntime(7465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prog3/com.example.prog3.ShowCars}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 8 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

My getAllCars Method:

```
public List<AutoEntry> getAllCars() {
    List<AutoEntry> autoentrys = new ArrayList<AutoEntry>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_CARS, allColumnsAuto, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        AutoEntry autoentry = cursorToCar(cursor);
        autoentrys.add(autoentry);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return autoentrys;
}
```

and this is my Cursor method:

```
private AutoEntry cursorToCar(Cursor cursor) {
    AutoEntry autoentry = new AutoEntry();
    autoentry.setFarbe(cursor.getString(1));
    autoentry.setHersteller(cursor.getString(2));
    autoentry.setName(cursor.getString(3));
    autoentry.setSonderaustattung(cursor.getString(4));
    autoentry.setAbteilungID(cursor.getLong(5));
    autoentry.setProgrammID(cursor.getLong(6));
    autoentry.setAusgeliefert(cursor.getString(7));
    autoentry.setBarcode(cursor.getInt(8));
    return autoentry;
  }
```

For the completness, here is my Insert method:

```
public void insertCar(String hersteller, String name, String farbe, String sonderausstattung, int abteilungID, String ausgeliefert, int barcode, int programmID) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_Hersteller, hersteller);
        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_KFZTyp, name);
        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_Farbe, farbe);
        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_SONDERAUSSTATTUNG, sonderausstattung);
        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_Ausgeliefert, ausgeliefert);
        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_AbteilungID, abteilungID);
        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_ID_BARCODE, barcode);
        values.put(Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_ProgrammID, programmID);

        try {
            openDatabase();
            long insertID = database.insert(this.TABLE_CARS, null, values);

            Cursor cursor = database.query(this.TABLE_CARS, allColumnsAuto, Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertID, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            AutoEntry autoentry = cursorToCar(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            closeDatabase();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error  inserting entry!" + ex.toString());

        }
}
```

How am I supposed to fix this that he starts at Row 1 or that my Data is stored at Row 0?

**EDIT**

```
private String[] allColumnsAuto = { Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_ID,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_Farbe,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_ID_BARCODE,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_Hersteller,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_KFZTyp,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_SONDERAUSSTATTUNG,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_AbteilungID,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_ProgrammID,
        Databasehandler.CAR_COLUMN_Ausgeliefert };
```

Answer (score 3):

Since **column indexes are 0 based** (as rows are - and as everything in Java is), you can't reference the **non existing column 8**.

So simply replace this

```
private AutoEntry cursorToCar(Cursor cursor) {
    AutoEntry autoentry = new AutoEntry();
    autoentry.setFarbe(cursor.getString(1));
    autoentry.setHersteller(cursor.getString(2));
    autoentry.setName(cursor.getString(3));
    autoentry.setSonderaustattung(cursor.getString(4));
    autoentry.setAbteilungID(cursor.getLong(5));
    autoentry.setProgrammID(cursor.getLong(6));
    autoentry.setAusgeliefert(cursor.getString(7));
    autoentry.setBarcode(cursor.getInt(8));
    return autoentry;
  }
```

with this

```
private AutoEntry cursorToCar(Cursor cursor) {
    AutoEntry autoentry = new AutoEntry();
    autoentry.setFarbe(cursor.getString(0));
    autoentry.setHersteller(cursor.getString(1));
    autoentry.setName(cursor.getString(2));
    autoentry.setSonderaustattung(cursor.getString(3));
    autoentry.setAbteilungID(cursor.getLong(4));
    autoentry.setProgrammID(cursor.getLong(5));
    autoentry.setAusgeliefert(cursor.getString(6));
    autoentry.setBarcode(cursor.getInt(7));
    return autoentry;
  }
```

Even better if you reference your columns by column **name**, instead of by column **index**

Something like:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Column_Name"));
```

in your case:

```
autoentry.setHersteller(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CAR_COLUMN_Hersteller)));
```

Comment: Yeah this works thanks, but the other thing is, "0" is actually my Car ID which is always "null" even tho I declared it as autoincrement, so my "Barcode" doesn't even get read by my cursor

Comment: This is another question.

Comment: If i try it with cursor.getColumnIndex, it shows me this:
03-11 16:27:11.730: E/CursorWindow(21054): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 8 columns.

Comment: **Impossible**. Or `you didn't pass the correct column name` (a non existing column name will produce that error).

Comment: I copied your code and changed the column name. They are all set correctly :/

Comment: Did you pass this (just to name one): `CAR_COLUMN_Hersteller`?

Comment: Yeah I copied the exact code you gave me and changed it with the other ones as well.

Comment: OK, try passing this `"Hersteller"`. Nothing should change, but... There's something I don't understand. Wait! did you change the database structure after the first execution?

Comment: It's still the same Error
Uhm yeah a few times but I deinstalled my application and installed it again and made the necessary adaptations

Comment: Maybe you forgot to increase the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant. Without increasing that, the `onUpgrade()` method will never fire.

Comment: Even if I increase the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant it still throws the ERROR

Comment: Can you provide the value of `allColumnsAuto`? Because I suspect there's something strange in the column list.

Comment: **1** It should be `private String[] allColumnsAuto = new String{ ...` **2** You're also including the ID as the first (0) column (try not to include it).

Comment: Yeah it's still giving the same Error

Comment: By the way, I don't use `query()`. I use `rawQuery()`, which lets me write the query in full SQL syntax.